# List/Review of EC2 alternatives?

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualhost, virtual-machines, amazon-web-services, rackspace-cloud

Are there any other web hosting providers that allow me to create and clone virtual machines like EC2 does?

What I know:

- Azure is no alternative (no root access, .NET only, no binaries).

Known alternatives

- Rackspace Cloud hosting
- Gogrid

Is there anything else? Especially, is there **anything** in continental Europe or Asia?

Comment: Linode allows cloning VMs.

Comment: You might find http://www.slicify.com interesting (full disclosure - this is my company). We offer a crowd-sourced compute platform that is much cheaper than EC2, and is currently targeted at back-end processes like media conversion, data analysis etc. We're working on supporting generic web hosting too.

Answer (score 3):

Two lists of IaaS providers:

1. [www.cloudorado.com](http://www.cloudorado.com/) - it is actually a price comparison for cloud computing, but could be limited to a list of providers
2. [www.cloudharmony.com](http://cloudharmony.com/clouds) - they also provide benchmark for subset of the list

Answer (score 0):

There are an amazing number of virtual machine providers, though Amazon is by far the largest single provider.  Amazon **does** have services in Europe or Asia, though it may be difficult to find another single provider that covers both areas it's likely that you could find different providers that cover both of those areas.

As far as an exhaustive list, I don't know of one but I haven't really looked.  It seems like the number of places that provide virtual hosting is practically unlimited.  Probably start with google and narrow it down by regions you are interested in and see if you can narrow the search down to those that can allow you to clone or provide machine instance images...